# Why does fetchone()[0] return a 'Nonetype'

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to store the employeeid value from employee table, to get the specific row I use the following command on Python:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT*FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE first_name = %s AND last_name = %s", (employee['firstname'],employee['lastname']))
```

followed by

```
employeeid=cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

why does employeeid have value Nonetype?

Comment: Sounds like the query didn't return any data. Check rowcount and print out the entire cursor results

Comment: I sincerely doubt it has value `Nonetype`. Probably it has value `None`, whose type is `NoneType`, which you saw in some error you didn't show us.

Comment: At any rate, if a column in the database has the SQL value `NULL`, and you `SELECT` it and `fetch` it in Python, what you get is `None`. So that's probably what you're seeing.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: That would raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: @abarnert I think SterlingArcher is right... if there are no rows, then `fetchone` returns `None`, and `None[0]` raises `TypeError: 'NoneType' ...`. Not `IndexError`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Ah, yeah, `fetchone` should either return `None` or raise an exception here, not return an empty row. But still, there's no way `employeeid` will be `None` (or `Nonetype`…) after that; the assignment won't even happen.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, but I don't trust the OP's description (I learned to never do that). I suspect the assignment is just shown one line above the `TypeError: ...` line and that the OP is misreporting it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Well, you have to trust _some_ part of the description; otherwise the answer could just be "Java 1.3 doesn't have a `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, so you either need to upgrade to a later version, or get a third-party implementation, or just use `TreeMap`, since you aren't using multiple threads anyway". :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason `fetchone()[0]` returns `None` is almost certainly that the first column in the first row matching your `WHERE` clause has a `NULL` value.

Since you're just doing `SELECT *` rather than providing a column list, the first column could be any of the columns in the table. If you specifically want the `employeeid` column, you should `SELECT employeeid`.

Also, since you're not using `ORDER BY`, the first row could be any of the matching rows. So make sure there aren't multiple rows matching your `WHERE` clause (unless you expect there to be). It's possible that you have one "good" row with a value of 23, plus another "bad" row with a value of `NULL`.

---

As StefanPochmann points out, it's also possible that you didn't find any rows, and you've misinterpreted the results. If a query returns nothing, the `fetchone()` call will either return `None`, or raise an exception. In this first case, your statement would cause an error like `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`, because `cursor.fetchone()[0]` is effectively doing `None[0]`. In the second case, the exception from `fetchone` itself might mention `NoneType` somewhere. In neither case is `employeeid` ending up with the value `NoneType` as you claim, but if you're not looking in the right place, you might have somehow convinced yourself that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here, [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143659/cursor-fetchone-returns-none-even-though-a-value-exists)

7

When you call execute, the results are computed and fetched, and you use fetchone/fetchmany/fetchall to retrieve them.

In your case, your query returns a single row as the result, so calling cursor.fetchone in the if causes the result to be fetched and subsequently thrown away, so another call to fetchone will yield None as the pointer has already advanced past the only row in the result set.

The idiomatic sqlite way of checking if data exists, is to query a row, and test its truthiness -

Answer (score -1):

While you could be looking at a null valued column in a valid row, I strongly suspect that you did not match any rows.  You can check if you matched a row by printing the results of your `cursor.fetchone()`.  I think you did not match any rows because of the way you sent your parameters to sql.  inserting them into the string, you need to quote the string parameters like:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT*FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE first_name = '%s' AND last_name = '%s'", (employee['firstname'],employee['lastname']))
```

the preferred option is  pass them in as sql parameters like:

```
stmt = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?"
result = cursor.execute (stmt,(employee['firstname'],employee['lastname']))
```

Comment: The OP didn't tell us which DB-API library he's using for PostgreSQL, but most of them use the `%s` paramstyle (or the non-standard `$1` paramstyle), not the `?` paramstyle, so this answer is going to make things worse.