# cursor.fetchone() returns None even though a value exists

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to figure out how to fetch a single value from a UserID and print it in the console. My current piece of code keeps returning "None" even though there is a value for Currency for the UserID I am searching.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT Currency FROM ServerUsers WHERE USERID = %s" % (userid))
    if cursor.fetchone():
        a = cursor.fetchone()
        print(a)
```

Comment: You have (a) unbalanced parentheses and (b) a great chance for SQL injection attacks. Don't use % string formatting on SQL queries!

Comment: Hi, thank you. I fixed the parantheses but it still returns none. I am not worried about sql injection attacks since it's just a personal project between a few friends.

Comment: Exactly that attitude had created many large IT resisters. So fix your query arguments as shown at https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute .

Comment: How many rows do you expect from this result?

Comment: You're calling `fetchone()` in the `if` statement, throwing that result away, then calling `fetchone()` again.

Comment: @Klaus D. Thank you for alerting me I will try to fix it today.

There is only one row per user, and I want to fetch a certain user's currency amount and print it to the console.

Thank you, removing the if statement fixed it. I thought the value would stay.

Comment: You don't have to remove the `if`, you just need to store the result of the first call so you don't lose it. In fact, I'd recommend retaining the `if`, it's good practice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `execute`, the results are computed and fetched, and you use `fetchone`/`fetchmany`/`fetchall` to retrieve them.

In your case, your query returns a *single* row as the result, so calling `cursor.fetchone` in the `if` causes the result to be fetched and subsequently thrown away, so another call to `fetchone` will yield `None` as the pointer has already advanced past the only row in the result set.

The idiomatic sqlite way of checking if data exists, is to query a row, and test its truthiness -

```
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result:
    print(result)
```

Comment: I was today years old when I learned that the word "truthiness" existed! :') - Cheers for the answer here, didn't realize you could check the true/false of the object like that.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem as you had. I used Sqlite and Pycharm Editor, I fixed the problem by refresh the database I use in Pycharm (View -> Tool Windows -> Database -> Refresh). I know the success rate is low but I hope this helps somebody experienced the same problem.