# query database using sqlite3.connect and check for matching results

Tags: python, sqlite, if-statement, discord.py, nonetype

My Discord bot queries a database and checks if there is a matching entry. To check for a matching entry I am using an if statement like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143659/cursor-fetchone-returns-none-even-though-a-value-exists). But somehow my code is not working as expected:

```
def check_db_entry():

    message = 'Some Message.'
    user_id : int = 1234

    # check if user already exists in database
    # connect to database
    con = get_connection() 
    cur = con.cursor() 

    # search in database
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM user WHERE id=?', user_id)
    result = cur.fetchone()

    if result:
        print(f'\nUser found in db with {user_id}.\n')
    else:
        print(f'\nNo user found in db with {user_id}.\n Create user')

    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

None of my 2 print statements get printed actually. Which is strange because, the `if` or `else` statement should work.

The connection to my database was successful. I already tested this many times just with `print(str(result))` Here my code for database setup:

```
def create_database():

    if not os.path.exists('db'):
        os.mkdir('db')

    # database setup
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect(SQLITE_DB_PATH)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id INTEGER NOT_NULL, balance REAL NOT_NULL, text1 TEXT NOT_NULL, text2 TEXT NOT_NULL)')
        con.commit()
        con.close()
    except Error as e:
        print('Failed to setup database.\n' + e)
        exit(1)


# connect to the database, returns connection object
def get_connection():

    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect(SQLITE_DB_PATH)
        return con
    except:
        print('Unable to connect to database. Please try again later.\n')
        exit(1)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You mentioned you're using discord.py. The `sqlite3` library is blocking, you should use an async library such as `aiosqlite`. But apart from that,  there's nothing wrong with the if-else, any idea which line your code's stuck on (perhaps add a few more prints to find out)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchone()` returns `None`, which is not the same as `false`, if the query did not return any rows and this is what you should check.

So change to this:

```
if result is None:
    print(f'\nNo user found in db with {user_id}.\n Create user')
else:
    print(f'\nUser found in db with {user_id}.\n')
```

Also, you should pass the parameter `user_id` as a tuple:

```
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM user WHERE id=?', (user_id,))
```

Also, `NOT_NULL` means nothing for SQLite, although it does not throw an error.
You should use `NOT NULL`:

```
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;') # execute once to drop he table that you created
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id INTEGER NOT NULL, balance REAL NOT NULL, text1 TEXT NOT NULL, text2 TEXT NOT NULL)')
```

Answer (score 0):

def search_habit():

```
sqliteconn = None

try:

    sqliteconn = sqlite3.connect('dbname.sqlite3')

    # print("Connected to Database Successfully.")
    dbconn = sqliteconn.cursor()
    
    habit_id = input("Enter Habit Id to search: ")
    habit_id = int(habit_id)

    command = """SELECT HabitId,HabitName,Description,Period,Born,Start_Date,Due_Date,Streak,Max_Streak,Max_Days,
                                Break,HabitStatus FROM habits_tracker WHERE HabitId = :hbt_id"""
    dbconn.execute(command, {'hbt_id': habit_id})
    records = dbconn.fetchall()
    lenrecords = len(records)

    if lenrecords > 0:

        for row in records:
            print(row)

    else:
        print("\nCurrently, There Is No Record Available.....")

    sqliteconn.commit()
    sqliteconn.close()

except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print("Failure: ", e)

except Exception as ex:
    print("Failure: ", ex)

finally:
    if sqliteconn:
        sqliteconn.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).